# Scala total function as partial function

Tags: scala, partial-functions

Since a total function is a special case of a partial function, I think I should be able to return a function when I need a partial.

Eg,

```
def partial : PartialFunction[Any,Any] = any => any
```

Of course this syntax fails to compile. My question is, is it possible to do this, and if so what do I need to do to get the syntax right.

I know I can do the following, but this is just an out-of-curiousity-question

```
def partial : PartialFunction[Any,Any] = {
  case any => any
}
```

Comment: Note that there is a `PartialFunction.apply` method: `def partial = PartialFunction[Any,Any]{ any => any }`

Comment: @senia, you should enter your comment as the answer as I believe it's correct and should be what the op is looking for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `PartialFunction.apply` method:

```
val partial = PartialFunction[Any,Any]{ any => any }
```

You could import this method if you want to make it shorter:

```
import PartialFunction.{apply => pf}
val partial = pf[Any,Any]{ any => any }
```

Comment: I'm going to upvote this because I did not know you could do that, but it's still not quite what I was hoping for. I think this is probably more work than just doing { case any => any } right. This apply is probably very useful when you already have a function rather than defining inline I guess.

Comment: I always try and use language features if they fit my needs first before writing my own code instead.  I guess you just need to determine if this fits your needs or not...

Comment: I don't really have any needs in this case (excuse the pun :)). I was just writing a partial function today that simply returned the input, and I thought an inline total function would have been nice. I ended up doing case { any => any} but I would it would make a good SO question.

Comment: @monkjack: You'll use it in case if you already have a function (`PartialFunction{identity}`) or if you want to use it as part of expression: `partail orElse pf(identity)`.

Comment: hi, I know it's an old question, but could anyone come up with a reason of NOT having that conversion available implicitly? So if I have sth like that in scope `implicit def lift[I, O](f: Function1[I,O]): PartialFunction[I,O] = PartialFunction(f)`. Could I shoot myself in the foot with this?

Comment: As of **Scala 2.13.5** a `PartialFunction.fromFunction(identity[String] _)` will do the trick whilst `PartialFunction(identity)` results in `PartialFunction.type does not take parameters`.

Comment: A more concise way that works for **Scala 2.13.5** is `(identity[String] _): PartialFunction[String, String]` or `(identity[String] _): String =/> String` if you `import scala.{PartialFunction => =/>}`

Answer (score 4):

A `FunctionN` is **not** a total function:

`val evilFun: Int => Int =
  n => if (n < 0) sys.error("I'm evil!") else n`

In other words, all Scala functions are partial functions. Therefore `PartialFunction` just gives you a way to inspect the partial function via `isDefinedAt` and chain partial functions via `orElse`.

It could make sense to get rid of `PartialFunction` altogether and have `isDefinedAt` at the level of `FunctionN` with function literals and lifted methods implementing `isDefinedAt` as always `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have the concept switched.

```
PartialFunction[-A, +B] extends (A) ⇒ B
```

However, you can't use a superclass value where a subclass is expected because the subclass is more specific.  So you can't return a `Function1` value from a method typed to return a `PartialFunction`.

The inverse works though - [you can use a subclass where a superclass is expected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). So you can return a `PartialFunction` from a method typed to return a `Function1` (with the same type parameters):

```
scala> def f: Any => Any = { case a => "foo" }
f: Any => Any

scala> f(1)
res0: Any = foo
```

In this particular case you can always convert a `Function` to a `PartialFunction`, so the `PartialFunction.apply` method is provided.

```
def apply[A, B](f: A => B): PartialFunction[A, B] = { case x => f(x) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have the concepts the correct way though, as I was referring to the fact a total function is a specialized case of a partial function (in general math not in Scala), so if you ask for a partial function, I should be able to give you a total function as that still fulfils the criteria. It was really just a kind of off the cuff, I wonder if, type of question, could I do ( any => any ) instead of case { any => any }. I really am turning into a Scala-zealot when I'm worried about saving a few characters :)

Comment: Gotcha - you're coming at it from the mathematics point of view.  I thought you were thinking about the OO p.o.v.

Answer (score 0):

Time has moved on, Scala is at **2.13.5** and what is shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20891356/969122) is deprecated since Scala **2.12.5**:

> For converting an ordinary function f to a partial function pf, use `val pf: PartialFunction[A, B] = { case x => f(x) }`. For creating a new PartialFunction, use an explicit type annotation instead, like in `val pf: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case 1 => "one" }`.

Also, consider the `import scala.{PartialFunction => =/>}` (in contrast to regular, total, functions `=>`). Since partial functions require writing out the type (aka adding type annotations) this saves you a lot of manual typing and improves readability, e.g.:

```scala
val yourPf: String =/> String = {
  case SomeRegEx(s) => s
}
```

Side note: On my machine `PartialFunction.apply` even results in the error `PartialFunction.type does not take parameters`.

Answer (score -4):

i think youre looking for the convenience method called "lift" which turns a partialfunction into a function1 (returning the result wrapped in an option).

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.PartialFunction

speaking of the taxonomy; i think you got that backwards - a partialfunction is a subtype of function1

Comment: Your answer is backwards.  The op is looking for a facility to turn a total function into a partial function and not the other way around.

Comment: PartialFunction is indeed a subtype of Function in scala land, but in maths land a total function is a special case of a partial function.

Comment: The question is not ambiguous at all.

Comment: can you pls explain? cause i had in mind exactly what you said.